# Mongodb Aggregation limit by percentage of number of results

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, limit

I have a collection of orders as:

```js
Orders:
{
  //some typical order fields
  cancelationMoment: {
    type: Date
  },
  
  consumer: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: 'consumer id required'
  }
  
}
```

I want to obtain the consumers who have more cancelled orders (top 10%).

My current implementation is:

```js
db.orders.aggregate([
 {$match:{ cancelationMoment: { $exists: true } }},
        {"$group" : {_id:"$consumer", ordersCanceled:{$sum:1}}
        },
        
        {$sort:{"ordersCanceled":-1}},
       
        { $limit:  2}
        
        ]);
```

But I want to obtain not just the top 2, but the top 10%. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could save a variable with the range of the collection and then manipulate as you needed.

```
var total = db.orders.find({ }).count();

db.orders.aggregate([  
    { 
        $limit: total * 0.1
    }
]);
```

**Update:**

Well using the stage "$count" will affect the projection of the result, but you can directly use the previous code into your aggregation stages.

```
db.orders.aggregate([  
    { 
        $limit: db.orders.find({ }).count() * 0.1
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that that this variable cannot be computed within the aggregate command, right?

Comment: @AlejandroFernandez-Montes I make an update, hope will be useful.